# Series over countable index set and subset

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, solution-verification

Let's assume that $\sum\limits_{k\in J}a_k$ is convergent, i.e. there exists a bijection $\varphi:\mathbb{N}\to J$ such that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}|a_{\varphi(k)}|$ converges. Now we take an countably infinite subset $M\subsetneq J$.

We claim that the series $\sum\limits_{k\in M}a_k$ is also convergent. The reason for this is the monotone convergence theorem (for sequences/series):

We know that there exists a bijection $\psi:\mathbb{N}\to M$ because $M$ is an infinite subset of $\mathbb{N}$. Moreover, we have that
$$
\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}|a_{\psi(k)}|\leq \sum\limits_{k\in J}a_k \text{ and clearly } \sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}|a_{\psi(k)}| \text{ is monotone increasing}.
$$
So $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}|a_{\psi(k)}|$ is convergent due to monotone convergence theorem and hence $\sum\limits_{k\in M}a_k$ converges.

---

However, fellow students told me that this is not correct (not telling where the proof breaks or what exactly is missing). I still believe that this is sufficient but maybe I have missed soemthing.

Comment: I don't know who told what, but the claim surely holds true.

Comment: @metamorphy, sure the claim is true, but how do I show it rigorously?